# Accessing MXML components within ascript files

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How do I get round the following error: Access of undefined property pMatrixBack
How do I access this component from within the ascript file?

```
// src/index.mxml

<s:Application>
  <s:Group id="iMatrix" width="100%" height="100%" dragEnter="WorkRows.acceptEnterHandler(event)" dragDrop="xyz.action(event)">
    <assets:PMatrixBack id="pMatrixBack" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </s:Group>
</s:Application>

// src/ascript/xyz.as

package xyz
{
  static public function action(event:DragEvent):void
  {
    var bitmap:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(pMatrixBack); //Error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you handling the event in a different class? and why is the eventhandler static?
handle the event where it happens (index.mxml) and then call a method of another class.

eventhandler in index.mxml

```
private function onAction(evt:DragEvent):void
{
    // you can access pMatrixBack here
    myObj.doSomethingWithPMatrix(pMatrixBack);
}
```

Comment: var group:Group = event.currentTarget as Group; bitmap = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(group.getElementAt(0) as IBitmapDrawable); This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First Check Whether the xyz object created

you cannot access directly, u can get only by the

event.currentTarget as IUIComponent.

that too in the dragEnter function.

Comment: var group:Group = event.currentTarget as Group;